# Ruby 1.9 print Array is not Unicode

Tags: ruby, unicode, puts

Why are `puts` and `print` results with Unicode characters not the same:

```
# encoding: utf-8

puts ['裤']
print ['裤']

裤
["\u88E4"]
```

even though they are the same when they are not in array?

```
puts '裤' 
print '裤'

裤
裤
```

Is it possible to change `print` so it always prints Unicode?

Comment: which is your version if ruby?

Comment: my version is 1.9.3, just standart

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the difference:

```
puts ['裤']
# 裤
# => nil
print ['裤']
# ["裤"]=> nil
['裤'].inspect
# => "[\"裤\"]"
RUBY_VERSION
# => "1.9.3"
```

But I think it was because of `:print` method prints containment of the array without joining its values together, just dump it. I believe that it uses `:inspect` to print it out. I can't reproduce it, but you try to execute the following `['裤'].inspect` on your system.

Comment: `['裤'].inspect` prints `["\u88E4"]`, the same as `print ['裤']`

Comment: May be it is because my OS(windows) is Chinese. But other languages has the same problem: `print ['я']; print 'я'` -- `["\u044F"]я`

Comment: @Qiao may be, but I think it is because of your ruby version, and revision. My one is *1.9.3p448*

Comment: @.majioa my is `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]`. That is strange. Not a big deal, but it bother me when debugging with Unicode text.

Comment: @Qiao I believe it is the deviation of the build. have you tried an other rubies versions or builds?

Comment: @.majioa nope, I changed to ruby `1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]`, same result

Comment: I mean that the problem is with the mingw build